# Facebook "Likes" box css styling?

Tags: css, plugins, facebook

I want to display which users like my facebook page with a widget in my website. I have tried the official widgets but they work with an iframe, and it is not possible to style them. They have a white (or black, those are the only two choices) background, and a border and font styling that look horrible on my site.

Is it possible, with a different plugin or whatever, to show a) the number of users who like my fb page and b)the profile pictures of some of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible check this tutorial out here,

http://www.speckygeek.com/how-to-add-facebook-like-box-to-your-website/

You can style the fanbox to fit your theme. The key is including a css attribute to the `<fb:fan>` tag, linking it to your own stylesheet.

Comment: It works, although you have to use the old fb "fans" plugin. Hope they don't discontinue it soon.

Comment: @agente_secreto it will: FBML is deprecated and will fail starting june 1, 2012 - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/